# UWP - Set foreground color to dynamic light and dark theme color programmatically

Tags: uwp, colors, themes, foreground

I am using the following to change the foreground color of a `TextBlock` in `UWP`.

```
 textBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
```

How should I change the code so that I may use a dynamic light and dark theme color e.g. `SystemBaseHighColor`? A list of colors is available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources

Answer (score 1):

It is more complicated to create the same effect as `ThemeResource` in the code. Need to do the following:

1. Get the resource through `Resources["resourceKey"]` and convert it into Brush and assign it to `TextBlock.Foreground`.
2. handle theme changes (such as [ThemeListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/themelistener))
3. Reassign

In comparison, a more appropriate method is to create a TextBlock Style. When creating a `TextBlock`, get the `Style` and assign it to `TextBlock.Style`.

```xml
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="CustomTextStyle">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}" />
</Style>
```

```cs
textBlock.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["CustomTextStyle"];
```

Setting the style of TextBlock in this way eliminates the need to manually handle theme changes.